# How to display custom dialog box when application comes to foreground after clicking on Push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-broadcastreceiver

I have one custom dialog box which I want to display after user clicks on the Push notification. I am using `FirebaseMessagingService` here.

Below is my code for receiving push notification. I am creating an intent and broadcasting it.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

   if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Cons.INTENT_FILTER);

        try {
            // getting my data here
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(key, data);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

In my base activity I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to receive intent and display dialog box.

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       // I am getting data from intent.
        bundle.putSerializable(key, data);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        dialogFragment.show(transaction, "dialog");
    }
};
```

I am able to see the dialog box with all data if app is in foreground. This code doesn't work if app is in background or if the app is not running.

I tried to look for solutions which says get running state of the app and put some if conditions accordingly. I want to know if some other solution is there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple make the activity as dialog and use it.

**Set dialog theme to your activity:**

`<activity name=".MyDialogActivity" android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>`

Comment: I do not want to show my activity as dialog. Please read my question carefully. Thanks.

Comment: I know your requirement. you can't show dialog without activity. Create Activity instead of DialogFragment.

Comment: I have activity already. My second piece of code is in Activity.

Comment: I want to show dialog box on the top of the current activity.

Comment: I completely aware of your implementation. You have implemented broadcast receiver in your activity to show dialog fragment. But what I'm saying is to create an Activity and show it as dialog. Start the dialog activity directly from Firebasemessaging service

Comment: do you want to show the dialog or both dialog and activity?

Comment: Both dialog and activity. My dialog is not full screen dialog.